# What is an Object Graph in the entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm currently studying about the entity framework, in particular the self-tracking entity generator and POCO entities. I have come across the term "object graph" a couple of times in my reading but no definition / explanation. What is an "object graph" in the context of the entity framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your root question has nothing to do with EF itself.  An "object graph" is a data structure resident in memory of class instances.  For example if you had:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Person Manager { get; set; }
}
```

and a bunch of things in memory thusly:

```
Person monkey = new Person()
                    {
                      Name = "Me",
                      Manager = new Person()
                                    {
                                      Name = "CTO",
                                      Manager = new Person()
                                                    {
                                                      Name = "Chairman",
                                                    }
                                    }
                    };
```

You would have a [Directed Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) that holds me, my boss, and his boss.  Basically, we're talking about [Data Structures 101](http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Data_Structures_101).